# Getting "illegal access to loading collection" error

Tags: java, hibernate

When I execute my program without implementing `hashcode()` and `toString()` then it works fine. But as soon as I include `hashcode()` and `toString()` then I get this "illegal access to loading collection" error.

My hbm files are

**1) booking.hbm.xml**

```
<many-to-one name="userId" class="User" column="user_id"
        insert="true" update="true" cascade="save-update" >
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="flightId" class="FlightSchedule"
        column="flight_id" cascade="all" not-null="true">
    </many-to-one>

    <set name="passenger" table="passenger79215" lazy="false"
        inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
        <key column="reference_id" />
        <one-to-many class="Passenger" />
    </set>
```

**2) Passenger.hbm.xml**

```
<many-to-one name="referenceid" class="Booking" lazy="false"
        insert="true" update="true" column="reference_id "
        cascade="save-update">
    </many-to-one>
```

**3) User.hbm.xml**

```
<set name="booking" table="bookings79215" lazy="true"
        inverse="false" cascade="save-update">
        <key column="user_id" />
        <one-to-many class="Booking" />
    </set>
```

Can anyone explain the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your hashcode and equals methods are not working properly. Make sure that they are correct. `toString()` has nothing to do with collection classes but hashcode and equals does.

I assume that you have overridden both hashcode and equals and not only hashcode.

[`Object#hashCode()` (Java Platform SE 7 )](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode())

Comment: Hello ravi... i have Overrided like this 
HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj);
ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);

Comment: You are relying on a third party tool to generate your hash code, which may fail to generate distinct hashcode based on your member variables. If you have a field that holds the same value for two different objects, you may get a wrong hashcode. 

try generating hashcode yourself (or if u happen to use Eclipse, inside your class right click->Source->generate hashcode and equals)

Comment: hello ravi... i also generated Hashcode() and equals() in the way u provided and it is still giving the same error...

Comment: check which properties are being used in your hashcode and equals. i guess one of ur properties are not unique. Can you share your code in your question.

Comment: Hey Ravi i got it... I removed the primary key from the hashcode and equals of booking class then the error stopped... Thnks for helping me dude :D...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not use the id field (managed by hibernate) in equals and/or hashCode.

Equals and hashCode should be implemented as a business logic equals.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but with a different resolution.  Like the OP I'm using Apache's hashcode builder.  My objects are Parent and Child with a one-to-many relationship.  The child includes Parent as a member so that the foreign key gets set properly.

The problem is that the hashcode builder uses all the member fields but when Child is being created its Parent hasn't finished loading yet.  When the hashcode builder references the Parent member Hibernate throws the exception because Parent is still loading.

The fix was to exclude the parent reference from the hashcode builder in Child's hashCode and equals:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
    return EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj, "parent" );
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this, "parent" );
}
```